# Adaptive design. Вопрос по размерам устройств

Tags: html, css

Хочу сверстать адаптив к сайту.
Соответственно в css прописываю

```
@media screen and (min-width: 319px) and (max-width: 321px)
```

и дальше описываю внешний вид при разрешении экрана в 320 px...

Вопрос: ***Есть ли какой-то список разрешений экранов для популярных смартфонов?***
Т.е. какие медиа скрин размеры ставить? Гуглил.. не могу найти именно для верстки норм размеров в пикселях.. Использую ресайзеры для мозилы и хрома. Там для стандартных размеров писал ксс, но не на iphone 4s, iphone 5, Highscreen Spider мои размеры не работают...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16443380/common-css-media-queries-break-points

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При создании адаптива используются не конкретные размеры, а их диапазоны. Пример можете посмотреть [здесь](https://stuffandnonsense.co.uk/blog%20/about/hardboiled_css3_media_queries) (также важно не забывать про ориентацию устройства).